# Citrix Client File Storage?

Tags: citrix, file-storage

I have a simple Windows App and I need to run it in the Citrix environment. It will be a Citrix app, so to speak.

The app saves some information to the local machine, to be exact`%appdata%/my-app-name/some-data.xxx`

That works perfect **without Citrix**, but I don't know where can I save the settings for each user properly in the Citrix environment? If I would the same logic, it would replace the information every time as the %appdata% is remote machine's path.

Is there a built-in solution in Citrix somethin like client storage solution?

Comment: `%appdata%` is already per-user, so what's the problem?

Comment: _"If I would the same logic, it would replace the information every time as the `%appdata%` is remote machine's path."_ - I'm having trouble understanding what you wrote, can you re-word it?